# Java compilation error when using wildcard generics extends

Tags: java, generics

I have a derived class `Father` and a base class `Parent` e.g.

```
public static class Parent {
}
public static class Father extends Parent {
}
```

I wonder why the followings are not allowed?

```
public static List<Parent> foo() {
    List<? extends Parent> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new Parent());  // 1. why is this not allowed?
    list.add(new Father());  // 2. why is this not allowed?
    return list;  // 3. why is this not allowed?
}
```

Comment: The duplicate explains why 1 and 2 are not allowed, and should implicitly explain why 3 is also not allowed. You may also want to check out: [Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>? Why are Java generics not implicitly polymorphic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-are-java-generics-not-implicitly-po/2745306).

Answer (score 1):

you can try this below code->

```
 public static List<Parent> foo() {
        List<Parent> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new Parent());  // 1. why is this not allowed?
        list.add(new Father());  // 2. why is this not allowed?
        return list;  // 3. why is this not allowed?
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Having `? extends Parent` as a generic parameter means that it represents a class that extends `Parent`, and therefore not `Parent` itself. To include `Parent` itself, simply use `Parent` as the generic parameter (i.e. `List<Parent>`).